# Как выбрать диалог пользователя со мной при такой структуре базы? Если никак то помогите собрать структуру

Tags: mysql, doctrine

Таблица для хранения общей информации по диалогу.

- id INT
- name VARCHAR(50)
- created TIMESTAMP

Таблица для хранения сообщений диалога - здесь будут храниться все сообщения привязанные к диалогу.

- id INT
- dialog_id INT
- sender_id INT
- text TEXT
- created TIMESTAMP

Таблица участников диалога

- dialog_id INT
- user_id INT
- joined TIMESTAMP (указывает, когда участник присоединился к диалогу,
  чтобы не показывать сообщения, которые были до того, как он
  присоединился)

Answer (score 0):

Так должно отработать.

```
select sender_id, text
from dialog
where dialog_id=1
order by created
```

Answer (score 0):

Вывод диалога `@dialog_id` для пользователя `@user_id` выглядит так:

```
SELECT m.created, m.sender_id, m.text 
FROM messages m
WHERE m.dialog_id = @dialog_id
  AND m.created >= (SELECT u.joined
                    FROM users u
                    WHERE u.user_id = @user_id
                      AND u.dialog_id = @dialog_id /* LIMIT 1 */ )
ORDER BY m.created /* , m.id */
```

Comment: Нужно выбрать диалог user - user не по id диалога, а по id юзера

Comment: @QuodNephilim Один и тот же пользователь может участвовать в нескольких диалогах, структура этого не запрещает, а определить, какой именно нужен диалог, из приведённых данных невозможно. Поэтому при получении точки входа пользователя в диалог указание конкретного диалога необходимо. Либо Вы неверно описываете смысл хранимых данных. Либо схема сама по себе неверна (если диалог - это диалог между тобой и одним пользователем, то user_id есть атрибут диалога). Либо исходные данные должны состоять как минимум из двух user_id - но и это не снимает проблемы с несколькими диалогами.

Comment: Спасибо, значит буду реструктурировать.